# Recurring payments Variables rp_invoice_id contain special character?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

for paypal In Recurring payments Variables does Variable Name "rp_invoice_id" contain special character like If i want to use email, Is it possible.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 0):

**rp_invoice_id**: it contains only alpha-numeric and max length will be 127 characters